# Getting an MSFT_Partition for a given MSFT_Volume

Tags: c#, wmi

I’m trying to get some details about a disk based on the drive letter and I’m having trouble getting the partition info for a given volume.

This is what I’m trying:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage");
var query = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {MSFT_Volume.DriveLetter='" + upperCaseDiskLetter + "'} WHERE RESULTCLASS = MSFT_Partition");

using (var partitionSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    scope,
    query))
{
    var partition = partitionSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Single();
```

And getting this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Management.ManagementException' in System.Management.dll

Additional information: Invalid object path
```

Maybe I’m approaching it wrong? I suppose a volume might exist on more than one partition? But still – I should get the “associators” query return some results unless MSFT_PartitionToVolume isn’t working for some reason?

This is what I’m trying to collect:

```
using (var volumeSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    @"\\localhost\ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage",
    $"SELECT Size, SizeRemaining, DriveType FROM MSFT_Volume WHERE DriveLetter='{ upperCaseDiskLetter }'"))
{
    var volume = volumeSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Single();

    result = new DiskProperties
    {
        LastRetrieved = DateTime.Now,
        DriveType = GetDriveTypeDescription((UInt32)volume["DriveType"]),
        FreeSpace = (UInt64)volume["SizeRemaining"],
        PartitionSize = (UInt64)volume["Size"]
    };
}

var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage");
var query = new ObjectQuery("Associators of {MSFT_Volume.DriveLetter='" + upperCaseDiskLetter + "'} WHERE RESULTCLASS = MSFT_Partition");

using (var partitionSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    scope,
    query))
{
    var partition = partitionSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Single();

    using (var physicalDiskSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                @"\\localhost\ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage",
                $"SELECT Size, Model, MediaType FROM MSFT_PhysicalDisk WHERE DeviceID='{ partition["DiskNumber"] }'"))
    {
        var physicalDisk = physicalDiskSearcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().Single();
        result.DiskSize = (UInt64)physicalDisk["Size"];
        result.Model = physicalDisk["Model"].ToString();
        result.IsSsd =
            (UInt16)physicalDisk["MediaType"] == 4 ||
            SSDModelSubstrings.Any(substring => result.Model.ToLower().Contains(substring)); ;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what's wrong with the `associators` query, but it seems like I overlooked the very simple solution - `MSFT_Partition` also has a `DriveLetter` column...

```
using (var partitionSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    @"\\localhost\ROOT\Microsoft\Windows\Storage",
    $"SELECT DiskNumber FROM MSFT_Partition WHERE DriveLetter='{upperCaseDiskLetter}'"))
```

Note though that this won't be populated for a VHD drive.